# Multi line Regex Expression for vs2015 selection

Tags: c#

I am trying to find and Replace.

Eg:

```
 If(something)
 {
 }
 else
 if(something)
 {
 }
 else
 {
 }
```

I need to replace the above "/nelse/nif" as "else if" in many number of files, but I am unable to select in Regex to find and Replace.
Please help

Need a Proper Regex to use in vs2015 or any other possibilities could help.

Comment: First you need to ask a proper question.

Comment: Do not worry about the new line.  You simply want to replace "else\s+{" with "else if{"

Comment: Try `\n\r?else\n\r?if`